# Input submit tag is displaying the value attributes text in IE 'submit query'

Tags: css

```
input.icon 
{
    border: 0;    
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    text-indent: -1000em;
}
input.edit {         
    background: transparent url('/edit.png') no-repeat center top; 
}
```

On an element like:

```
<input type="submit" class="icon edit" onclick="...." />
```

It renders fine in firefox, without the text on the image also.  In IE it shows the text of the value attribute.

**Why is that?**
*Actually i'm not even setting the value attribute and it is defaulting to 'submit query'.*

Also, I thought my CSS could be more specific by doing:

```
input.icon {
...
}
input.icon .edit {
...
}
```

But that didn't work for me not sure why, so I changed the 2nd definition too:

input.edit {
..
}

Why didn't `input.icon .edit` work?

Could I just as well put these styles on a div element?  What's the difference?

Comment: What does your html look like.  Does the button have BOTH the icon and edit classes?

Comment: yes, see above, my element didn't render properly so I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few questions there.  For the first one.  I'm not seeing the issue in IE8:

http://jsfiddle.net/rfYrq/

I do not see the text in IE8.

---

*Question 2: "Why didn't input.icon .edit work?"*

The meaning of `input.icon .edit` is, any element with the class of `edit` **within** an input element with a class of `icon`.  What you really wanted was any input with **both** the `edit` and `icon` classes.  That would be like this:

`input.icon.edit`

---

*Question 3:  "Could I just as well put these styles on a div element?"*

Yes.  If you are overriding the style of the button with your own css and apparently overriding the functionality of the button with an `onclick`, you can just use a div or a span or some other element depending on your situation.